# Comparing continuous and discrete distributions

Tags: probability

I guess my main question is how can I compare a continuous distribution to a discrete distribution. If I have their respective pdf/pmf how can I determine the probability P(continuous > discrete). Or equivalently how can one determine P(discrete > continuous).

The example I had given was between an exponential and a poison distribution for which I think the answer below was pretty apt.

Comment: Exponential is continuous and Poisson is discrete/countable

Comment: That is where my confusion arises. I don't know if they are comparable or not and subtracting them doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot find this probability without some extra assumption. If you assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent (a very crucial assumption) then you can compute the probability as follows:

$$P(X>Y)= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-2\lambda} \frac {(2\lambda)^{n}} {n!} P(X>n)$$ $$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-2\lambda} \frac {(2\lambda)^{n}} {n!} e^{-\lambda n}.$$ I will let you finish the computation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm interested in how you went about the first step, could you explain that a little more?

Comment: The event $X>Y$ is made up of the disjoint events $(X>n, Y=n)$ and $P(X>n, Y=n)=P(X>n) P(Y=n)$ by independence. @JB_Probs

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. But then in your second step you simplify the exponential to $e^{-\lambda n}$. Shouldn't it be 1 - $e^{-\lambda n}$

Comment: Also when I simplify your expression I result in: $e^{2\lambda(e^\lambda  - 1)}$ @Kavi Rama Murthy